# windows 8 desktop: bluetooth event listener

Tags: c#, c++, windows, bluetooth

I'm writing a windows 8 desktop app for the tablet that tracks the bluetooth radio status in order to monitor power consumption. Basically, I want to find out the initial radio status, as well as receive callbacks whenever the status changes. I've looked through the MSDN bluetooth functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but haven't been able to find anything about the event callback.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Is there a way to do this (preferably in C#, but C/C++ is fine as well)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no Bluetooth event regarding radio removal. You will be able to use the general hardware events to see device removal, that set-up by function RegisterDeviceNotification. See e.g.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal